# How to use oAuth State parameter on MSAL.NET

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to make usage of the `state` parameter which exists in OAuth2.0 [authorization flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) on a .NET Core project, using MSAL 4.0 but I couldn`t find a way to do it.

I want to provide/append a custom value (Redirect the user back to the Uri where they clicked the sign-in button, after AuthN succeeds).
To do that, I would also need to send the current Uri in 'state' and retrieve the `state` value back, but I don't see any method/property on `AuthenticationResult.cs` that would hold it.

So, how can I use the `state` parameter with custom data on a .NET Core project using MSAL?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use it, it's an optional security feature. MSAL.net employs 2 mechanism to prevent against attacks such as XSRF and man-in-the-middle: `state` and `PKCE`.

The state param is simply returned back by AAD. MSAL will compare the state param in the request with the state param in the authorisation code response.

Comment: can we use/set `nonce` ?