# How do I pass custom state with the MSAL.Net library?

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

I want to add Azure AD authentication to an existing set of ASP.Net web applications.  As part of the login/signin process, I want to keep track of information about the current user of my application that I will use after the signin is complete.  I guess I could just rely on standard ASP.Net session state management, but this seems like an appropriate use for the OAuth2.0 `state` parameter if I can figure out how to use it.

How do I pass custom state information to the IdP (in this case Azure Active Directory) which will be returned to my application upon authentication/signin, using MSAL.Net from an ASP.Net application?  There is information here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-js-pass-custom-state-authentication-request) about doing it with MSAL.js, but it doesn't seem directly transferable to MSAL.Net. There is also a prior question on SO ([How to use oAuth State parameter on MSAL.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798275/how-to-use-oauth-state-parameter-on-msal-net)) which seems to be effectively the same question, but the answer is not helpful, at least to me.

thanks

Martin

Answer (score 1):

MSAL uses the `state` param to protect against XSRF attacks. An explanation from developers is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56798275/how-to-use-oauth-state-parameter-on-msal-net).

Consider using cookies for this purpose.